# SQL to display null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL which displays a count result, however it omits rows that have nothing, i'd like it to display those which have nothing.

For example id like it to display a Fname, Sname and CName with a NULL even if there is no result

Currently it should display 115 results as there are 115 users but it only displays 57, I'm guessing this is because it won't display the null values

```
SELECT  u.Fname, u.Sname , c.CName, COUNT(t.Id)
FROM Table t INNER JOIN User u ON u.UId = t.Id INNER JOIN ComId c ON c.ComId = u.ComId 
WHERE c.ComId LIKE "NAME%"
GROUP BY u.Fname, u.Sname, c.CName;
```

Thanks

Comment: That query is invalid, it should raise an error. (You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY u.Fname, u.Sname , t.CName`.)

Comment: You can't use the same table alias `t` twice...

Comment: Updated the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `left join`s.  You need to start with the table that has everything you want . . . which seems to be the users table:

```
SELECT u.Fname, u.Sname, c.CName, COUNT(t.Id)
FROM User u LEFT JOIN
     Table t 
     ON u.UId = t.Id LEFT JOIN
     ComId c
     ON c.ComId = u.ComId AND c.ComId LIKE 'NAME%'
GROUP BY u.Fname, u.Sname, c.CName;
```

Once you start with `LEFT JOIN`, generally subsequent joins also need to be `LEFT` (or rarely `FULL`) joins.  Also, conditions on subsequent tables need to go into the `ON` clause to prevent the `WHERE` clause from filtering out the "extra" rows generated by the outer join.

Answer (score 0):

you have table t as  main table  (from) and left table  you should use one only  eg:

```
SELECT  u.Fname, u.Sname , t.CName, COUNT(t.Id)
FROM Table t 
LEFT JOIN User u ON u.Id = t.Id 
WHERE t.Name   LIKE "Name%" 
GROUP BY u.Fname, u.Sname, t.CName
```

and eventually you could also check for null value with ifnull

```
SELECT  u.Fname, u.Sname , t.CName, ifnull(COUNT(t.Id) ,0) 
FROM Table t 
LEFT JOIN User u ON u.Id = t.Id 
WHERE t.Name   LIKE "Name%" 
GROUP BY u.Fname, u.Sname, t.CName
```

anyway you should use a proper group by for all not aggregated  columns

Comment: I've used your solution, however it still doesn't display results which have null value, updating the code on my initial question

Comment: try add  a proper data sample  ..  you actual result and your expected  result as tabular text  (data ..not explanation only or image)